# How to display a window within a plugin when the pluggable Cocoa app only exposes a C++ API?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

I am developing a plugin for FileMaker Pro 11 Advanced on Mac using its C++ plugin API. I want to show an `NSWindow` on screen that is loaded via an XIB file, but I am unable to get the window to display without setting the "Visible at Launch" property of the window to YES in the XIB file.

I am trying:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```

The problem is, this does not make the window appear on screen. I have also tried:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:windowController];
```

and:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:window];
```

and:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

I am very new to Objective-C and Cocoa, so I am still learning basic stuff about creating GUIs on a Mac. However, I am not sure that my window controller, my window, or even `NSApp` are "hooked into" FileMaker Pro;  i.e. I don't know if my `NSApp` is the same as FileMaker's `NSApp`. Is this a dumb question?

How does `NSWindowController` successfully display the window on screen when "Visible at Launch" is set to YES? I don't want to continue using that property just to get my window on screen!

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to display a Cocoa window from a Carbon application. Did you call `NSApplicationLoad` first ? See [CarbonCocoaIntegration.pdf](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/CarbonCocoaIntegration.pdf) on the apple website for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'window' in your example? I'd expect that code to use either

```
[windowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil]
```

or

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
```

(or NSApp instead of NIL or whatever, the sender doesn't matter here, it's ignored, only the receiver is relevant). NSWindowController lazily loads its window, so the XIB is not loaded until you call -window. You're not directly accessing _window (or self->_window), the instance variable, right? Because that will just be NIL until the first time you call -window.

Also, as Jan already alluded to, FileMaker is very, very old and has very likely not yet been updated to use Cocoa for its user interface. You can mix Carbon (which FileMaker is probably still written in) and Cocoa, but there are lots of tiny little issues and gotchas, so I don't recommend it, especially when you are new to Cocoa. You'd have to learn both Carbon and Cocoa to troubleshoot a lot of the stuff you're doing.

BTW -- don't use NSApp. Use [NSApplication sharedApplication], which will make sure you get an NSApplication object back. NSApp may be NIL if you call it before anyone has ever called [NSApplication sharedApplication]. And again as Jan mentioned, for Carbon/Cocoa integration, you might have to call the function NSApplicationLoad() so Carbon knows you will now be creating a few Cocoa windows inside it. That will still not help you with the menu bar, though, which will still be Carbon.

Does the FileMaker SDK offer provisions for creating windows? You might have to resign yourself to writing your code against its C++ SDK. Alternately, create a stand-alone Cocoa application that creates your window and does the work, and create a tiny C++ plug-in that simply launches that application, hands it the data (e.g. by writing it to a file or sending an AppleEvent to your application, or sending the info over using Distributed Objects) and then at some point knows how to retrieve the data from your application and hand it back to FileMaker.